# sqlite return subquery multi column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a sqlite subquery with the following query which is calculating the hours and labour_rate. The only issue I now have is can I get the two columns from my subquery to output in the main query. I've tried to layout the query according to some of the web tutorials but need that little bit of help to get me over the finish line as I keep getting a syntax error

```
  SELECT c.customerID, c.customer, sum( ifnull(il.line_price, 0 ) )/10000 AS net,  
  FROM customer AS c
  LEFT JOIN invoice AS i
  ON c.customerID = i.customerID
  LEFT JOIN invoice_line AS il
  ON i.invoiceID = il.invoiceID
  (SELECT sum(( ifnull(tl.mon,0) + ifnull(tl.tues,0) + ifnull(tl.wed,0) + ifnull(tl.thurs,0) + ifnull(tl.fri,0) + ifnull(tl.sat,0) + ifnull(tl.sun,0) ) * s.cost_rate)/10000 AS labour_rate, 
  sum(( ifnull(tl.mon,0) + ifnull(tl.tues,0) + ifnull(tl.wed,0) + ifnull(tl.thurs,0) + ifnull(tl.fri,0) + ifnull(tl.sat,0) + ifnull(tl.sun,0) ))/10000 AS
  FROM timesheet_line AS tl
  LEFT JOIN timesheet AS t
  ON tl.timesheetID = t.timesheetID
  LEFT JOIN staff AS s
  ON t.staffID = s.staffID
  WHERE (c.customerID = tl.customerID) AND (t.date BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2015-12-01')
  GROUP BY tl.customerID) AS time1
  WHERE (i.date BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2015-12-01') AND (time1.customerID = tl.customerID)
  GROUP BY c.customerID
  ORDER BY c.customer ASC
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few syntax errors in here. The first (and possibly most important) is you have to `JOIN` your subquery to the rest of the result set.  So after

```
LEFT JOIN invoice_line AS il
  ON i.invoiceID = il.invoiceID
```

you will need to add another JOIN statement:

```
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         SUM(...) AS labour_rate, 
         SUM(...) AS hours,
         tl.customerID
     FROM
     ...) AS time1 
 ON <your join condition>
```

You will have to select some sort of field in your sub query that you can join back to the the invoice on i.e. `tl.customerID`. 
Also, in your subquery you cannot reference a field that is outside of it, so where you have `WHERE (c.customerID = tl.customerID)` in your subquery it will fail because you are trying to reference `c.<fieldname>`.  It needs to be moved to the `ON` part of the `JOIN` clause. Once you get your `JOIN` working correctly then you can just change your outer-most `SELECT` to something like

```
SELECT c.customerID, c.customer, sum(ifnull(il.line_price,0))/10000 AS net, time1.labour_rate, time1.hours
```

Here's an example of how I would do it:

```
SELECT c.customerID, c.customer, sum( ifnull(il.line_price, 0 ) )/10000 AS net, time1.labour_rate, time1.[hours]
FROM customer AS c
    LEFT JOIN invoice AS i
    ON c.customerID = i.customerID
    LEFT JOIN invoice_line AS il
    ON i.invoiceID = il.invoiceID
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT 
            sum(( ifnull(tl.mon,0) + ifnull(tl.tues,0) + ifnull(tl.wed,0) + ifnull(tl.thurs,0) + ifnull(tl.fri,0) + ifnull(tl.sat,0) + ifnull(tl.sun,0) ) * s.cost_rate)/10000 AS labour_rate, 
            sum(( ifnull(tl.mon,0) + ifnull(tl.tues,0) + ifnull(tl.wed,0) + ifnull(tl.thurs,0) + ifnull(tl.fri,0) + ifnull(tl.sat,0) + ifnull(tl.sun,0) ))/10000 AS [hours],
            tl.customerID
         FROM timesheet_line AS tl
            LEFT JOIN timesheet AS t
            ON tl.timesheetID = t.timesheetID
            LEFT JOIN staff AS s
            ON t.staffID = s.staffID
        WHERE (t.date BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2015-12-01')
        GROUP BY tl.customerID) AS time1
    ON c.customerID = time1.customerID
WHERE (i.date BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2015-12-01') 
GROUP BY c.customerID
ORDER BY c.customer ASC
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and more importantly your explanation. You've explained it extremely well, something which has actually sunk in. Hopefully I can add another subquery to calculate other costs from other set of tables to get the final output desired.